# Can't find sendmail Courier binary when configuring clamcour 2.0

Tags: install-from-source, clamav

when i install clamcoure and run this command

```
clamcourdir# sudo ./configure
```

It gives me this error :

`configure: error: Cannot find sendmail Courier binary`

Comment: You seem to be making progress with your problem, can you make sure you go back to your past postings and either accept answers or post how you solved that step so the next person who tries to build this can benefit? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You must install Courier before you can get clamcour working.

If you have installed at least `courier-base` and probably `courier-mta` then clamcour is probably looking in the wrong location for courier's sendmail.

Try this :

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/courier/bin
sudo ln -s  /usr/sbin/sendmail  /usr/lib/courier/bin/
```

You should see a result that look similar to this :

```
%ls -l /usr/lib/courier/bin/sendmail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 2011-02-21 23:28 /usr/lib/courier/bin/sendmail -> /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

If you haven't installed courier yet, make sure you install the courier-* packages to support the functions you want, e.g. :
`sudo apt-get install courier-base`
`sudo apt-get install courier-mta`